# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION during Tomcat deploying

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have an application which is able to run properly in tomcat, but when added a dependency of another application in maven I encountered the error below when deploying on `Tomcat` (the build works just fine):

`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION`

Comment: I guess the added dependency is also available in the in the lib folder of the tomcat. (Could be in another version) Please use provided as scope for your dependency.

Comment: Please post your pom.xml.

Comment: Generally this is because incompatible versions of library jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be conflicts in the jars as imported by your application and as that are already present in the lib folder of tomcat directory.
Remove the duplicate jars from the lib folder tomcat directory. That may resolve the issue.

Comment: Will using maven shade plugin help ?

Answer (score 0):

[Teja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3673490/teja): has maven shade helped you anyhow? I'm following a similar issue in Jetty now and I'm interested in trying different approaches. So far I've discarded different versions that may be adding noise.

Comment: It didn't actually, I made my jars consistent to make it work